# Como hacer una captura de pantalla que no este en deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screenshot

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una captura de pantalla/screenshot. Y casi todo lo que he visto de como añadir el Bitmap y guardar la captura. Pero me sale en Android Studio que esta en Deprecated, como por ejemplo en la linea  **String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";** Esta en Deprecated el getExternalStorageDirectory()

Y ademas lo debo de estar implementando mal, digo yo. Porque no funciona, no guarda la captura de pantalla, cuando le pulso al boton.

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo recordar que los servicios nativos de screenshot en **Android** unicamente están permitidos para aplicaciones del sistema, pero hay una especie de "engaño" que puede ser que te funcione.

Te puedes crear una clase ScreenshotManager con este aspecto

```
public class ScreenshotManager {
    private static ScreenshotManager mInstance;

    private ScreenshotManager() {}

    public static ScreenshotManager getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (ScreenshotUtil.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new ScreenshotManager();
                }
             }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }


    public Bitmap takeScreenshotForView(Activity activity) {
        View viewScreenshot = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        viewScreenshot.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), 
                                               MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                               MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getHeight(), 
                                               MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        viewScreenshot.layout((int) viewScreenshot.getX(), 
                              (int) viewScreenshot.getY(), 
                              (int) viewScreenshot.getX() + viewScreenshot.getMeasuredWidth(), 
                              (int) viewScreenshot.getY() + viewScreenshot.getMeasuredHeight());

        viewScreenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        viewScreenshot.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewScreenshot.getDrawingCache());
        viewScreenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return screenshot;
    }
}
```

Más información -> http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-take-screenshot-programmatically/

Comment: Muy interesante!, pensé que actualmente con las API más recientes no se podía realizar esto por "seguridad" o únicamente desde una app de sistema :-0